# useNavigate from react-router-dom not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

When clicked, my handleDelete function isn't navigating to the '/items' page. Whereas my handlePostSubmit, when clicked, does navigate to '/items'. What happens instead is that it stays on the current page and I get errors in the console saying that it can't read 'location' because it's undefined, since the item is deleted. So, I know the first part of the function is working. It's just the navigate that's bugging.

```
// ItemHook.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { BASE_URL } from "../../../globals";
import axios from "axios";

export const useItem = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    let { id } = useParams();

    let [item, setItem] = useState({
        location: '',
        category: '',
        item_name: '',
        description: '',
        unit_measure: '',
        case_size: '',
        vendor_name: '',
        vendor_code: ''
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setItem({ ...item, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        // console.log(item)
    }

    const handlePostSubmit = async (e) => {
        console.log(item)
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/item/create`, item);
            navigate("/items");
            return res
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const getItem = async () => {
        let item = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/item/${id}`)
        setItem(item.data[0])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            getItem(id);
        }
    }, [id])

    const updateItem = async () => {
        let url = `${BASE_URL}/item/update/${id}`
        await axios.put({
            url,
            method: 'put',
            data: item
        })
    }
    const handlePutSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateItem();
        setItem({
            location: '',
            category: '',
            item_name: '',
            description: '',
            unit_measure: '',
            case_size: '',
            vendor_name: '',
            vendor_code: ''
        })
        console.log(item)
        axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/item/update/${id}`, item)
        navigate('/items');
    }

    const handleDelete = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/item/delete/${id}`);
            navigate("/items");
            console.log(res.data)
            return res.data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return {
        item,
        handleChange,
        handlePostSubmit,
        handlePutSubmit,
        handleDelete
    };
};

export default useItem;
```

```
// ItemForm.jsx
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setCardTitle } from '../slices/cardTitleSlice';
import Card from "./card/Card";
import Button from './Button';
import { setButtonName } from "../slices/buttonNameSlice";
import { useItem } from "./card/card-functions/ItemHook";

const ItemForm = ({ editMode }) => {

    // Dispatch action to Redux store
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // change cardTitle=""
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setCardTitle('New Item Form'));
    }, [dispatch]);

    const { item, handleChange, handlePostSubmit, handlePutSubmit, handleDelete } = useItem();

    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <Card
                    className="home-card"
                    cardTitle=""
                >
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.location}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'location'}
                        placeholder={'location'}
                        className='location-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.category}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'category'}
                        placeholder={'category'}
                        className='category-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.item_name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'item_name'}
                        placeholder={'item'}
                        className='item-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.description}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'description'}
                        placeholder={'description'}
                        className='description-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.unit_measure}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'unit_measure'}
                        placeholder={'unit of measure'}
                        className='uom-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.case_size}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'case_size'}
                        placeholder={'case size'}
                        className='case-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.vendor_name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'vendor_name'}
                        placeholder={'vendor_name'}
                        className='vendor-input'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={item.vendor_code}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name={'vendor_code'}
                        placeholder={'vendor_code'}
                        className='vc-input'
                    />
                    <>
                        {editMode ? (
                            <>
                                <div>
                                    <button
                                        type='submit'
                                        id='save-button'
                                        onClick={handlePutSubmit}
                                    >
                                        Save
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button
                                        type='submit'
                                        id='delete-button'
                                        onClick={handleDelete}
                                    >
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <button
                                type='submit'
                                id='add-button'
                                className='card-button'
                                onClick={handlePostSubmit}
                            >
                                Add
                            </button>
                        )}
                    </>
                </Card>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default ItemForm
```

```
// ItemDetails.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setCardTitle } from '../slices/cardTitleSlice';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'
import { BASE_URL } from '../globals'
import ItemForm from './ItemForm';
import { useItem } from "./card/card-functions/ItemHook";

const ItemDetails = (props) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(null);

    let navigate = useNavigate()
    let { id } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (itemData) {
            dispatch(setCardTitle(`Edit ${itemData}`));
        }
    }, [dispatch, itemData])


    const handleDelete = async (_id) => {
        await axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/item/delete/${id}`).then(
            () => navigate('items'))
    }

    const { item } = useItem();

    return (
        <div className='items'>
            <ItemForm
                title="Edit Item"
                item={item}
                editMode={true}
            />
        </div >
    )
}

export default ItemDetails
```

url before "Delete" button is clicked: http://localhost:3000/items/645692cc72ddae2801f4ebd3

url after "Delete" button is clicked: http://localhost:3000/items/645692cc72ddae2801f4ebd3?location=new&category=new&item_name=new&description=new&unit_measure=new&case_size=new&vendor_name=new&vendor_code=new

url I'm expecting: http://localhost:3000/items

Errors in console:

```
ItemForm.jsx:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
at ItemForm (ItemForm.jsx:30:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)

react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the 
<ItemForm> component:

at ItemForm (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:455:5)
at div
at ItemDetails 
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:335:76)
at EditItem
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46120:5)
at main
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58:80)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46053:15)
at BrowserRouter 
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45529:5)
at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42852:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

I've tried  `navigate('/items', { replace: true });` to replace the current history and `navigate('/items', {});` to override the previous state that was set in the url.

Comment: If there are any errors in console log, post them

Comment: Why there is no `e.preventDefault()` but there is in the other functions?

Comment: This isn't enough code to provide enough context to see what the issue is. Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]. Are there any errors and/or rejected Promises from the DELETE request that prevent the rest of the `try` block from executing?

Comment: @Konrad if I use e.preventDefault() it prevents the item from being deleted

Answer (score 0):

The issue was inside of ItemHook.jsx inside the handlePostSubmit function. The return res was causing the page to try and render the deleted item.